# How to encode a NFC tag to pair a smart phone to a bluetooth device

Tags: windows, bluetooth, nfc

Preface: I am brand new to NFC and not a programmer. Doing the best I can to figure out how to accomplish what I'm looking to do and learn in the process.

**I am attempting to write a NFC tag (using a NXP NTAG215) with GoToTags on Windows using an ACS ACR122 reader/writer via USB connection that pairs a smart phone with a bluetooth speaker.**

The trouble I'm running into is that GoToTags does not have a bluetooth record built in. I have been searching a lot on the NFCForum (and Google in general) to try to understand how to encode the tag with the bluetooth MAC address I want to pair to, but I'm not sure which type of record in GoToTags to use to do it (or if it is possible). I have seen some binary content from NFCForum, but I don't have the fundamental understanding of programming/NFC to really do much with that information.

My options for records are Android App, Application, Bing Maps, Bing Search, Contact Info, Email, Facebook Profile, Geo Location, Google Maps, Google Search, Local File, Mime Type, Phone Number, Plain Text, Text Message, Twitter Profile, Uri, Website, and YouTube Video.

I was thinking I might be able to use the Mime Type or Plain Text record to put in some magic string that asks users to pair (or automagically pairs) to the bluetooth speaker, but I'm really struggling to find what I need.

I have also tried using another NFC read/write software on Windows (NFC Tools) to write a bluetooth tag, but it does not work when I scan it with my text iPhone 7 Plus and when I read the tag with GoToTags, it shows an unknown record with a long data string "D220086170706C69636174696F6E2F766E642E626C7565746F6F74682E65702E6F6F620800000000000000."

This might simply be over my head (well, it obviously is right now), and it seems most people are using their knowledge of programming to create their own apps and software. I don't have a smart phone (just a friend's iPhone 7 Plus to try to read the tags I create on my Windows machine when I see them--so not that often) and I know there are a lot of Android apps that write bluetooth tags, but I want this to work from my Windows machine, if possible, using GoToTags.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mimeType you need is application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob

If you decode that Hex String to Text with https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter you get "application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob" as the mimeType.

Looking at the Hex string it has the right NDEF headers in front of the mimeType but comparing it to an Android App writes for "Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing" record, it writes 08 00 followed by the Mac Address in reverse

**Update:** From the bluetooth spec (Section 3.1) 08 00 is the OOB Optional Data Length (which includes the 2 bytes of itself + the 6 bytes of the Mac Address)

So if you look for "oob" + 08 00 or 6F6F620800 in your string as a pointer to where the MAC address should start then in the string this is correct. What you seem to be missing is any MAC address (It's all zeros), which is why the Iphone probably won't do anything with it.

More Details of the NDEF Spec can be found at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-NDEF_1.0.pdf

According to an NXP app reading this NDEF record it was stored as a "Short Record" Section 3.2.4 in the spec linked. and the 08 00 is part of the payload data

So Try writing with your windows software a mimeType record of "application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob" with the data of 08 00 + MAC address reversed.

E.g. If the MAC Address is A1:B1:C1:A2:B2:C2

The Hex data to write would be 08 00 C2 B2 A2 C1 B1 A1

**Updated:**
I did find the spec for bluetooth messages at https://members.nfc-forum.org/resources/AppDocs/NFCForum_AD_BTSSP_1_0.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am able to encode a Mime Type with GoToTags of "application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob" with Hex Payload "0800C2B2A2C1B1A1" and then read it with NFC Tools (in Windows) and it appears as a Bluetooth record. I haven't tested this with a smart phone, yet, however.